# How to solve armv6, armv7 problem in order to distrubute my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

In order to distribute my app via App store,
Is it nessecary to make my app excutable in both armv6 and armv7?

After I upgraded xcode version to 4, My app don't be compiled.
Because external libraries don't support armv7.

This is error message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WXRadioItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
  "_ExpandString", referenced from:
      -[DebugController runPressed:] in DebugController.o
      -[DebugController lngPressed:] in DebugController.o
      -[SkinViewController expandString:] in SkinViewController.o
  "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      -[WunderRadioAppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:] in         WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FavoriteViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsAvailableNotification", referenced from:
      -[DebugController gotRunNotification:] in DebugController.o
      -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EnhancedAlertView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DebugController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadioTimeBrowser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_gStreamingAudioPlayerTimerMax", referenced from:
      -[PreferenceViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in PreferenceViewController.o
      -[PreferenceViewController makemp3Buffer:] in PreferenceViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidStopNotification", referenced from:
      -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
      -[SkinViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in SkinViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MusicViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBSettingsManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in PreferenceViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsAndKeyChainStorage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in DebugController.o
      objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsDoneNotification", referenced from:
      -[DebugController gotLngNotification:] in DebugController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_URLBackgroundOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SkinViewController.o
  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidPlayNotification", referenced from:
      -[SkinViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in SkinViewController.o
  "_Status_SetNewStatusString", referenced from:
      -[SkinViewController setShowingPlay:] in SkinViewController.o
  "_Status_GetCurrentStatus", referenced from:
      -[LevelMeterView updateBargraph:] in LevelMeterView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help/suggetion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happen If 'Valid Architecture' is 'ONLY armv 6'? Then Can I submit my app to App store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can submit it that way, but it's not preferable since the compiler will not optimize for newer phones.  You should get updated libraries to support armv7 and i386